# Программное поднятие трубки

Tags: java, android

Коллеги, возникла необходимость в поднятии трубки во время звонка из приложения

Googling подсказал вариант решения, но в моем случае он не работает для 4.0

Разрешения в манифесте:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE"/>
```

Сам класс:

```
public class Controller {
    private static final String TAG = "CONTROLLER_1";

    private static Boolean flag = false;
    private static Context contextApp;
    private enum methods{accept, abort}

    public static void setFlag(Boolean value){flag = value;}

    public static void mergeMethod(String command, Context context){
        contextApp = context;
        if (command.equals(methods.accept.name())) {
            acceptCall();
        }
    }
    private static void acceptCall(){
        Log.d(TAG, "acceptCall");
        if (flag) {
            Log.d(TAG, "SUCCESS");
            Intent headSetUnPluggedintent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_HEADSET_PLUG);
            headSetUnPluggedintent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_RECEIVER_REGISTERED_ONLY);
            headSetUnPluggedintent.putExtra("state", 1);
            headSetUnPluggedintent.putExtra("name", "Headset");
            try {

                contextApp.sendOrderedBroadcast(headSetUnPluggedintent, null);
            } catch (Exception e) {

                e.printStackTrace();
        }

            Intent putBtn = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_BUTTON);
            putBtn.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_KEY_EVENT, new KeyEvent(KeyEvent.ACTION_UP, KeyEvent.KEYCODE_HEADSETHOOK));
            try {
                Log.d(TAG, "onAccept");
                contextApp.sendOrderedBroadcast(putBtn, "android.permission.CALL_PRIVILEGED");
            }
            catch (Exception e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            flag = !flag;
        }
     }
}
```

Можете подсказать, в чем причина?

Comment: Вот тут подробно описана задачка : [Ответ](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23097944/can-i-hang-up-a-call-programmatically-in-android)